# linear functional vs linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I observe some similarity between linear functional and linear operator, say

- continuous linear functional $\iff$ bounded linear functional
- continuous linear operator $\iff$ bounded linear operator

Can I say linear functional is a special case of linear operator where the vector space becomes a field?

Comment: Yes, [that's the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_form).

Comment: @Conifold Thanks!